# After downloading the new beta version, application is not updated

Tags: android, google-play

I posted a new beta version in google developer console, but device doesn't see new available beta version. It has been more than 3 days since I released. May be the reason that the application has been installed to the computer, not downloaded from google?

Comment: The app needs to be signed using the same keystore. Was yours signed with a different keystore?

Comment: No, I signed with the same keystore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you upload an Alpha Testing apk, it doesn't appear in google play as production app. What I've done is to create a community in google+ and then I associate that community to my app. Here I show you where you can do it:
[image]
and
[image]

If you dont want to create a community like me, you can also add the gmail of the "testers" that you want to test your alpha/beta app. Don't forget to add your own email ;).

Hope this help you.

Comment: I added a group of testers and they have confirmed, but they don't receive any messages about new beta version

Comment: I strongly recommend testers to download the app over the browser instead of try to find your app on their mobiles. You have to shared the link with your testers, and after they accept to be tester of your app, they are able to download your app.
The problem is that the new version are not notified to your testers. They have to go to "google play" find your app in their own list of downloaded apps and check if it has any update. That is what I've done to my testers in order to my new version would be downloaded.

Comment: They are able to update your app if they have it already install. They only have to look for it in their installed google play apps and update appears. Remember that the update is not available immediately. Google needs a few hours to make your update visible